# convert mixed list to floats in python

Tags: python, int

I'm trying to write a function that will remove non-floats and convert all int to floating numbers. I've included some print statements from my own debugging process. I'd like the transformation that adds ".0" to int to return a list.

```
std_in= ['1', '2', '2.1', 'ab1', '1ab']
```

Results
    ['1', '2', '2.1']

Desired results
    ['1', '2', '2.1']
    
    ['1', '2', '2.1']

```
def float_sort(std_in):
    float_sort = std_in
    sorted_float = ""
    float_sort = " ".join(float_sort)
    float_sort=re.findall(r"\b(^[+-]d+\e+\d+|\-\d+\.\d+|\-d+|\d+\.\d+|\d+)\b", float_sort)
    print(float_sort)
    [float(i) for i in float_sort]
    sorted_float = sorted(float_sort, key=len)
    print(type(sorted_float))
    sorted_float = " ".join(sorted_float)
    print(sorted_float)
    sorted_float = sorted_float.split()
```

Comment: You question isn't quite clear. Can you correct your sample input output?

Comment: Do you want the output list to be a list of `int`s or a list of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers provided by `ettanany` and `Patrick Haugh` are good but just for fun here is my answer:

```
l = ['1', '2', '2.1', 'ab1', '1ab']

def float_generator(mylist):
    for n in mylist:
        try:
            yield float(n)
        except ValueError:
            pass

print list(float_generator(l))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
res = []
std_in = ['1', '2', '2.1', 'ab1', '1ab']

for i in std_in:
    try:
        res.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

**Output:**

```
>>> res
[1.0, 2.0, 2.1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use approach that parser feature, should only parse data.

```
def parsefloat(str):
    try:
        return float(str)
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Then, apply `parsefloart` on each item of list.

```
res = filter(lambda x: x, map(parsefloat, std_in))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output as strings:

```
def float_check(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

l = ['1', '2', '2.1', 'ab1', '1ab']
print([i for i in l if float_check(i)])
```